# Release resource when agent can't exit

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm using an assembly block to simulate the assembling process of a product. This assembly block pushes the assembled products into a queue with a size of 1. Sometimes it happens that this queue is full when the assembly block finishes its process so the assembly waits until the queue gets free. During this time the resource is still seized by the assembly block and displayed as busy.

I want to display the idle time of the resources so i want the assembly block to finish the assembly, leave the product on its place and release the resource, which won't start another assembly until its workplace is free again.

Is there any way to get such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way using the following structure where you have a wait block before the entry of each one of the part types that will compose your products... you also have an auxiliary queue after the assembler and before the queue that you mentioned which is of size 1... I will assume that you have only 1 resource available because otherwise I think it wouldn't make sense to have a queue of size 1, but you can extend it to using more resources if you need to. The wait blocks and the auxiliary queue blocks have maximum capacity:

[image: model structure]

Now create a function called startAssembly that will do the following:

```
if(auxiliaryQueue.size()==0 && wait.size()>=assembler.quantity1 && wait1.size()>=assembler.quantity2 && resourcePool.idle()>0){
    for(int i=0;i<assembler.quantity1;i++)
        wait.free(wait.get(i));
    for(int i=0;i<assembler.quantity2;i++)
        wait1.free(wait1.get(i));
}
```

This function starts the assembling process only if the resource is free, if there is no products in the queue of size 1, and if there are enough parts to assemble the product.

You will call this function in 3 different places using `startAssembly();`

1. In the on exit of the assembler blokc
2. In the on enter of the wait block
3. In the on enter of the wait1 block

Comment: Thank you. I get an error "index 0 is out of bounds 0 of size 0". In front of wait1 I added the construct you proposed here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511248/anylogic-simulate-material-stored-in-containers/50512879#50512879). In the conveyor block in the on full exit i have this code `wait9.free(wait9.get(0));`. When I remove this part it works, but it pushes all agents directly to the assembly block. I guess there is a problem with the `wait9.get(0)`.

Comment: do this: if(wait9.size()>0) wait9.free(wait9.get(0));

Comment: Ok that one worked, but now it assembles one product and then stops. There are enough agents in the wait blocks, the resource is free and the auxiliaryQueue is empty. If I delete the checking of the size of the wait blocks in the function it returns the error "index 1 is out of bounds of size 1". When I look at the wait1 block at this moment it has the quantity 1. Is it possible that the agents appear one after another even if I used freeAll() on the previous wait block?

Comment: this is because you are designing everything incorrectly... and this conveyor thing is different than the question asked here.. I would have to give you a looong answer to explain exactly how to do it...

Comment: I assume you are not going to explain that to me? What am I designing incorrectly?

Comment: I don't even know what wait9 is in your model.. how do you expect me to help you..

Comment: I did reduce your suggestion a little since quantitiy2 is always full. I now have a wait block in front of quantity1 and the auxiliaryQueue after the assembler block. Whenever an agent exits the assembler a new agent is injected to quantitiy1. In the startAssembly() function I only check for size of auxiliaryQueue and if there is a idle resource available. Aditionally I print out the results of these checks. The first time startAssembly() is called everything is fine, but the second time (on exit of assembler block) there is no idle resource available. The resource seems to be still seized.